# $D_4/N$ is isomorphic to a cyclic group of order $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'am a little confused about how to go about this:

> Check $D_4/N$ is isomorphic to a cyclic group of order $2$.

Here, $D_4$ refers to the group of symmetries of a square and $N$ is a the normal subgroup of rotations.

Well, I know the order of $D_4$ is $8$ and the order of $N$ is $4$. So the order of $D_4/N$ must be two.

I also know $N= \{R_0,R_1,R_2,R_3\}$ and $D_4 = \{R_0,R_1,R_2,R_3,M_1,M_2,D_1,D_2\}$.

So $D_4/N$ is essentially the left cosets of $N$ in $D_4$.

This is where I am stuck, I know there are two elements which are left cosets of $N$ in $D_4$ but I don't know how to find them.

If I can find them, then I can show $D_4/N$ is isomorphic to a cyclic group of order $2$.

Thanks!

Comment: How many groups of order two do we have?

Comment: Well, dont we have 2?

Comment: Which two? ${}{}$

Comment: Im not sure, groups of order two in...? I mean, Z2 is a group of order 2....is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb Z_2$ is a group of order two. Indeed, this is the only group of order two. Thus $D_4/N$ **is** isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: Ok, so how can I show that? Im not sure what the elements of D4/N are..I know they are left cosets, but Im not sure which left cosets...

Comment: one sentence **So $D_4/N$ is essentially the left cosets of $N$ in $D_4$** is not clearly written, and *that* would be the stuck. Try to repair and understand this sentence.

Comment: You do not need to find a left coset explicitly to show that $D_4/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$. That the order of $D_4/N$ is two alone implies already that $D_4/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: Ok, but you arent saying that if two finite groups have the same order they are isomorphic are you?

Comment: No,  that is only true if THERE IS ONLY ONE GROUP of that order.  If the order of the group is prime, there is only one group of that order, up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two elements in $D_4/N$, namely $N$ and $M_1N$. Note that $M_1N=M_2N=D_1N=D_2N$. Since $(M_1N)^2=M_1^2N=N$, we have that $D_4/N=\langle M_1N\rangle$.